# Should the merchandise and swag tags be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, synonym-request

After digging around meta for posts about official Stack Exchange items, I've noticed a few different tags for this topic:

[merchandise](/questions/tagged/merchandise) - For questions regarding Stack Exchange-branded merchandise and its distribution.

[swag](/questions/tagged/swag) - Stuff We All Get - promotional gifts

Also marginally related:

[t-shirt](/questions/tagged/t-shirt) - For questions about Stack Exchange shirts?

[shop](/questions/tagged/shop) - For questions relating to the Stack Exchange Shop and its products.

Because the Stack Exchange store is now closed, is there any difference between swag and merchandise?  If the store was still open, I could see that [merchandise](/questions/tagged/merchandise) would be used for official items that could be purchased, and [swag](/questions/tagged/swag) used for promotional items given away that would not necessarily be for sale.

I feel that [merchandise](/questions/tagged/merchandise) and [swag](/questions/tagged/swag) now occupy the same domain and should be synonyms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any particular reason to do anything with these tags. The questions which were talking about merchandise in the store in the past are not all entirely relevant to swag in general, nor are general questions about swag entirely relevant to merchandise.

We do have full intention of eventually creating a store again in the future. It's only a matter of *when* we think that will be a good idea. It was originally closed down due to the amount of headache it caused between a variety of different issues; at the time it just wasn't worthwhile to have around. At some point, we grow and develop enough interest that having a store around does become worthwhile again.

Not to get everyone's hopes up, but the idea of having a store again did come up again recently. It's something our marketing team is interested in getting set up again, but we have no definitive timeline whatsoever on how long it'll take to get that set up because there's a lot of additional factors to consider in the process.

For now, I've updated the [swag](/questions/tagged/swag) tag wiki excerpt to be a bit more detailed.

> For questions about free gifts Stack Exchange sends out to its users for reaching milestones, contests, and other events as well as the processes behind them.

While  all of the items you receive as part of a swag package can be considered merchandise, there is much more to the swag process of information collection, how you get it, etc that is just not covered by a [merchandise](/questions/tagged/merchandise) tag at all.